# PHP - How to check if a db variable is true for any of a users blogs in wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, function, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite install with 100+ users with blogs. Some users have more than one blog.

Users can pay for their blogs (think of it as a donation scenario), or they can choose to have a free blog. If they have a free blog then there is a variable in wp_*Blog-ID*_options called `is_free_site` and it is set to 1. (*Blog-ID* relates to the users blog)

If the user is paying for their site, `is_free_site` will either be set to 0 or **the variable won't exist in the db at all**. See screenshot:

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1657353/0238f2bf2d49f0b165170be6c64ba3a3

I am trying to write a function called `does_user_pay` this will look to see if the current logged in user pays for *any* of their sites and if they do it returns true. This is so I can feed premium content to those who choose to pay

So for example, user A might have 2 sites, one which they pay for, one which they don't - so `does_user_pay()` should be true

User B might have 1 site which they don't pay for, `so does_user_pay()` will be false

user C might have 1 site which they pay for, so `does_user_pay()` will be true.

I am coding this into a custom plugin, here is what I have so far:

```
function does_user_pay() {
    global $current_user;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_blogs = get_blogs_of_user($user_id);

    // Need to write a function here that checks if any of the user blogs are paid for

    if(is_user_logged_in() && USER_HAS_PAID_SITE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do this check in this way (assuming user is logged and his id is stored in $user_id):

```
$blogs = get_blogs_of_user($user_id); // array with all user blogs
foreach($blogs as $blog){
    switch_to_blog($blog->userblog_id); // switch the blog
    $is_free_site = get_option('is_free_site', 0); // get the option value (if not exists, so the user paid, we'll get 0)           
    restore_current_blog(); // it's important to restore after a switch blog

    if($is_free_site == 0) return true;  // found a paid blog
}

return false; // not found a paid blog
```

Comment: Could we add is_user_logged_in() after $is_free_site == 0 then that will get rid of the assumption that the user is logged in right?

Comment: i think `if(!is_user_logged_in()) return false;` can be the first row of the function

Comment: Works like a treat!! Thanks - although it feels like it's slowing my site down a little - could be my internet connection though - do you think this would be quite a resource heavy piece of code?